# Writing to .txt file in columns with php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have an associative array in php, for example with the values:

```
"apple" => "green"
"banana" => "yellow"
"grape" => "red"
```

My question is, how can I write the keys and values for this array to a `.txt` file into two perfect columns?
By which I mean into two columns with a uniform distance between them all the way down

Comment: why do you want to do that ? and what type of file you are referring is it txt file or webpage ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Formatting purposes

Comment: suppose you want to put key and value into text file?? read more about file handling in php

Comment: @Lex, yes, formatting purposes, but for what medium?

Comment: again in which type of file ? because your question is vague without file type

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm writing to a .txt file

Comment: @Lex, checkout my response below, it caters for any length of word. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833521/writing-to-txt-file-in-columns-with-php/27833722#27833722

Comment: @thePav It accomplishes the same thing but it's a bit too much for what I need. This did the job 
    $text .= str_pad($key, 20) . "  " . $item . "\n";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **str_pad()** php function for the output.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

**Code:**

```
<?php
$fruits = array( "apple" => "green",
                "banana" => "yellow",
                "grape" => "red" );

$filename = "file.txt";
$text = "";
foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit) {
    $text .= str_pad($key, 20)."  ".str_pad($fruit, 10 )."\n"; // Use str_pad() for uniform distance
}
$fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Could not open log file.");
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write file!");
fclose($fh);
```

**Output:**

```
apple                 green     
banana                yellow    
grape                 red
```

**// Getting the length dynamically version.**

```
<?php
$fruits = array( "apple" => "green",
                "banana" => "yellow",
                "grape" => "red" );

$filename = "file.txt";

$maxKeyLength = 0;
$maxValueLength = 0;

foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) {
    $maxKeyLength = $maxKeyLength < strlen( $key ) ? strlen( $key ) : $maxKeyLength;
    $maxValueLength = $maxValueLength < strlen($value) ? strlen($value) : $maxValueLength ;
}

$text = "";
foreach($fruits as $key => $fruit) {
    $text .= str_pad($key, $maxKeyLength)."         ".str_pad($fruit, $maxValueLength )."\n"; //User str_pad() for uniform distance
}
$fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Could not open log file.");
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write file!");
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for long strings though, @Lex I've got a proper solution for words of large lengths.

Comment: @SuryaElite, What happens if the word is longer than 20 characters?

Comment: @Darren - I can just change the values. Yours seems right but doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Lex, see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833521/writing-to-txt-file-in-columns-with-php/27833722#27833722 it caters for all lengths of words.

Comment: @thePav I was just telling him str_pad() functionality. Getting the length dynamically is good idea.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I revised the functionality, and the below will work with a string (array key) of any length.

```
$longest = 0;
// find the longest string.
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $c = strlen($key);
    $longest = ($c > $longest) ? $c : $longest;
}

$distance = 5;
$str = '';
// now loop through and apply the appropriate space
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $c = strlen($key);
    $space = $distance + ($longest - $c);
    $str .= $key . str_repeat(" ", $space) . $val . "\n";
}

echo $str;
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/240450)

---

I don't understand why you'd want to do something like this, but this will do as you desire:

```
$str = '';
foreach($array as $key => $item){
  $str .= $key . "\t" .$item ."\n";
}
file_put_contents('path/to/file', $str);
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/240434)

---

<sup>*You'd obviously have to test the `file_put_contents()` to ensure it succeeded, but I'll leave that to you.*</sup>

You'd just have to change the ammount of tabs (`\t`) if you run into any long strings. In your case, it'd probably be best if you went with 2 (`\t\t`).

Comment: A tab wouldn't work if say one of the first words were long would it?

Comment: @thePav Check edit, OP will have to specify & provide more info :) but that was exactly what I was thinking. (the other way of counting blah blah wouldn't be beneficial at all)

Comment: @Darren - this is my issue. That the words are of different length. So the space in between them will vary. Usin \t or \t\t won't work since it doesn't keep a uniform distance between the columns

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a long shot, but you could possible do something like find the max array key length and then use that as a guide for how many spaces you want in between the words.

eg.

You could get the max array key length using `strlen()` like this:

```
$maxLength = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $item){
  if(strlen($key) > $maxLength){
    $maxLength = strlen($key);
  }
}
$maxLength += 5; //or any spacing value here
```

And then use `str_pad()` to add padding to the word like this:

```
$str = '';
foreach($array as $key => $item){
  $str .= str_pad($key, $maxLength, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . $item . '\n'; //add padding to the right hand side of the word with spaces
}

file_put_contents('path/to/file', $str);
```

This probably isn't the best solution but you could probably make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`$Offer` is your `array`

```
$file = 'people.txt';
$content = '';

foreach ($Offer as $key => $value) { 
   $content .= $key.'='.$value;
   // Write the contents back to the file
   file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```